# Finding Linear Differential Equations General Solution

Tags: linear-algebra, ordinary-differential-equations

**Find the general solution of $x'=Ax$ and find the fundamental matrix X(t) such that X(0)=I when $A=\begin{bmatrix} -3 & 4 \\ -2 & 1 \end{bmatrix}$**

So the eigenvalues are $\lambda_1=-1+2i,\lambda_2=-1-2i $ with respective eigenvectors $\begin{bmatrix} 1-i \\ 1 \end{bmatrix},\begin{bmatrix} 1+i \\ 1 \end{bmatrix}$

So the general solution should be $e^{-t}(\cos(2t)+i\sin(2))\begin{bmatrix} 1-i \\ 1 \end{bmatrix} $

Multiplied out, the general solution (found from separating the real and imaginary part) is

$x_1=e^{-t}[c_1(\cos(2t)+\sin(2t))+c_2(\sin(2t)-\cos(2t))]$

$x_2=e^{-t}[c_1\cos(2t)+c_2\sin(2t)]$

However, the book gives an answer

$x_1=e^{-t}[c_12\cos(2t)+c_22\sin(2t)]$

$x_2=e^{-t}[c_1(\cos(2t)-\sin(2t))+c_2(\sin(2t)+\cos(2t))]$

Where is the extra 2 coming from and why are the two switched? If it is not immediately obvious, instead give me a method to try to get to that solution please. Thanks for any help.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

$\begin{bmatrix} 1-i \\ 1 \end{bmatrix}\cdot (1+i) = \begin{bmatrix} 2 \\ 1+i \end{bmatrix}$ which is also an eigenvector. It appears the book used this instead. Odd to see the $2$s left next to the $c_i$ since they can be absorbed into the constants.

Comment: Huh, alright then. I there any reason to multiply by (1+i) there at any point? Or is this just different methods of finding eigenvetors? 

I found mine by just typing the matrix into Wolfram Alpha (since it's work I know how to do already) and got those eigenvectors. Maybe doing them on paper would get me that solution instead. In any case, would my solution still be correct?

Comment: The exact values of the constants may be different but after substituting the constants in and simplifying, they will be the same. No reason I know of to multiply that in but I've seen people who prefer the first component of a vector real.